# Trouble with MS Remote Web Deploy II6 6

Tags: msbuild, webdeploy, web-deployment-project

I am getting the following error when I run web deploy:

```
>C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets (3588): Web deployment task failed.
((3/25/2011 4:41:36 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.)  
(3/25/2011 4:41:36 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer. The entry type 'Unknown' was not expected at this time. The serialization stream may be corrupted.
```

I have successfully done this on other **IIS6** machines with no issues so I don't understand what is going on. The Remote Deployment Service is running and just to see if it mattered I started the service under an administrative group. That did not help.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the 2008 server with IIS 7 did not have all of the components installed.  Even though Web Deployment 2.0 seemed to have been installed by the Web Platform Installer, there were components that were incomplete due to communication issues with the MS servers.  In order to resolve this, I had to download the installation files on a separate machine, copy them to the server and then reinstall everything.  Very vague error for such an odd issue.